# Pegar informação resposta JSON

Tags: php

Boa tarde galera, preciso de uma ajudinha.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://pubproxy.com/api/proxy?api=...');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($data);
$proxy = $json->data->ipPort;
echo $proxy;
```

Não estou conseguindo extrair da página em json o ipPort. Resposta do site:

```
{"data":[{"ipPort":"83.169.202.2:3128","ip":"83.169.202.2","port":"3128","country":"RU","last_checked":"2018-07-22 09:05:20","proxy_level":"anonymous","type":"http","speed":"15","support":{"https":1,"get":1,"post":1,"cookies":1,"referer":1,"user_agent":1,"google":0}}],"count":1}
```

Já tentei destas formas:

```
$proxy = $json->data->ipPort;
$proxy = $json->ipPort;
```

Comment: `$json->data["0"]->ipPort;`?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam, não seria `$json->data[0]->ipPort`, sem as aspas?

Comment: @WeesSmith não lembro, por isso coloquei apenas em comentário, mas **acho** que ambos funcionam

Comment: resta saber se funcionou kk

Comment: já conseguiu a resposta?

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
echo 'ipPort: ' . $json["data"][0]["ipPort"];
```

Saída:

> ipPort: 83.169.202.2:3128

A propriedade `data` contem um lista com as informações que você precisa, neste caso obtemos só o primeiro valor no índice `0` que é `$json["data"][0]` para ter acessos aos dados.

Veja funcionado no [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d413720d0ec21d6ea1e71c6a026f2e9d3179cfb).

## Edição

Como mencionado pelo @GuilhermeNascimento, tem que passar `true` para a função `json_decode` que é o segundo parâmetro `bool $assoc` que transforma o objeto em um array associativo.

Comment: Não se esqueça de trocar `json_decode($data)` por `json_decode($data, true)`, para converter em arrays associativas ao invés de stdClass ;)

Comment: Tinha me esquecido só coloquei no exemplo no PHP Sandbox. @GuilhermeNascimento vlw vou colocar aqui :D